# Singular or Plural verb

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural

> Fire-detection data, satellite imagery, photographs and videos from the ground has indicated at least 80 large-scale fires in has areas across northern Rakhine State since 25 August, according to Amnesty International.

I found the line in " Independent News". Why " has indicated " is here where subject is plural? Is there any special case that permits " has indicated " here?

Comment: "have indicated" seems correct to me here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you found a rather commonplace error in English grammar. The subject is definitely plural, like you say, but ***has indicated*** is singular. The reason is ***from the ground*** splits the subject and verb, and ***ground*** is singular. There are no special cases where singular should be used with plural nouns. To a casual writer and reader who isn't paying close attention to grammar, it is easy to miss this error. However, to a professional writer, it is a sloppy mistake to make. And it's an even worse mistake for an editor or proofreader to miss the error and let it go through to publication. Such is the state of journalism today -- where barriers to publication are very low. However, you caught the error, which is great!